# Multiplication of 2D array matrices(Not matrix multiplication but normal multiplication to an element with the corresponding one)

Tags: java, output

I have an assignment to write a method that would perform piecewise multiplications.
My method header should be:

```
public static double [][] multiply(int [][] a, double [][]b)
```

Return null if the dimensions do not agree. In order to check for the first and second dimension use: a.length and a[0].length You can safely assume that the arrays are rectangular.

The matrices are in this form

```
  a  b  c  
  d  e  f
  g  h  i
```

&

```
  j  k  l
  m  n  o
  p  q  r
```

Here is what I came out with:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
a = new int [a.length][a[0].length];

for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<a[0].length; j++) {
    a[i][j]=(int)(randomGenerator.nextDouble()*255.0);
  }
}

for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<a[0].length; j++) {
    System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}

b=new double[b.length][b[0].length];
for (int i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<b[0].length; j++) {
    b[i][j]=randomGenerator.nextDouble()*255.0
      }

}

      double[][] result  = new double[3][3];
      result = a[i][j]*b[i][j];

      if([a.length]!=[b.length]&&[a[0].length]!=[b[0].length]){
      return null;
      }
      else{
      return result;
      }
```

Is it possible that the user choses the dimension himself ?
How can I do that?

Does this code multiply each element of the matrix with the other element of the matrix?

Are all the conditions satisfied?

Comment: I think you are missing some information here. For instance, the close }'s for the last for loop. In fact, your code looks rather jumbled together...

Comment: Just the code.. Does it make sense ? To multiply each element of 1 matrix with the other matrix ?

Comment: There is no ignoring braces, they are critical... Either posting them right or removing them will considerably help me or any future viewer to understand what's going on...

Comment: Okay .. my bad .. What about the content ?

Comment: As it is listed now, you aren't looping through the results properly, and it just won't work... I would focus on the portion around the result, and remove everything else, except a definition of a and b... Start at double[][] result and keep going until any loop around it is done.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your answer much ..

Comment: I'm a beginner in java so I really need some slow guidance

Comment: Just show us your code starting from `public static double [][] multiply(int [][] a, double [][]b)`. The generation of a[][] and b[][] should **not** be in your method since they are passed to your method. The general idea is that you want to loop through all possible values of i and j and calculate the value of result[i][j]. You're not doing that. And yes, the size of the result array should be dependent on the size of the input.